# Phalcon и Zephir

Tags: php, phalcon

Добрый день, подскажите конкретный код на Zephir - где его компилировать и подключить к Phalcon?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправь тег для начало на Zephir.

Читаем

http://zephir-lang.com/

Примеры

https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/tree/2.0.0/phalcon

https://github.com/lynx/lynx/tree/master/lynx

https://github.com/owl-framework/owl/tree/master/owl

Это отдельное расширение

zephir install

И добавляем в отдельный ini для загрузки:

```
echo extension=Имя расширения.so > /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/Имя расширения.ini
```